# SSRS report - merging 2 rows

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have been trying to solve this SSRS thing for long but not able to do so.

Scenario:

A report needs to be developed based on the following conditions for a restaurant:

2 CONDITIONS:

1) 3 days in the Current Full Week with value > 2%

OR

2) 5 days in the Current Full Week and Previous Full Week (i.e. across the last 2 weeks) with value > 2%

The report was designed accordingly, but now the restaurants are coming on 2 separate rows when they fall under both the conditions.

**Original**
[image]

**I want it as**

[image]

**Report structure:**

[image]

**Condition:**

[image]

[Note: Conditi is a just a true or false measure which gives True value (i.e 1) when the value is >2%.]

Comment: If you want to merge the rows then you'll need to use the Row Groups not the Visibility (that will just hide rows). Check the Grouping for that Row and see if you can maybe put in an expression to group the lines if they are the same restaurant.